# within the "last" 90 days

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I want to cancel a cell phone line. The small print states that if I cancelled a line "within the last 90 days", I can not be eligible for a promotion offered.
My interpretation is that once I get the promotion, I can now cancelled the line because it is not the last, or past 90 days. I would appreciate any input.

Comment: You should seek clarification from the phone company whether it was a condition of *getting* or of *keeping* the benefits of the promotion. As purely a language matter (i.e. not a matter of law), the snippet you've presented - in the context you presented it - suggests it's about *getting* the promotion. But you only quoted the time frame; the interpretation was supplied in your own words. So all we can say about the quote is that *something* related to a past period of 90 days. We can't say what that *something* was; we can't even point to when the 90 days ended based on the 5 words quoted.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("nothing to do with EL&U"), as this is a matter of logic rather than of English. What are the conditions **attached to the promotion**? If you don't read the fine print of *those* conditions, you're simply guessing about whether you can cancel the line once you've received the promotion.

Comment: If you've already received the promotion—does it matter if the ninety days are up or not? Could what you received be *revoked* in some way? (Logically, I don't see how the question about language makes any practical difference to what you can and can't do or receive.)

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of obligation rights in a non-US country, it would mean "within the last 90 days of you receiving this offer" If you cancelled before receiving the offer, the offer is not valid and the company may refrain from letting you benefit from it.

Should that be the case then you're in the clear, though it can't harm to ask customer support, as @Lawrence pointed out.